# Error net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES - How can I limit AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat, console.log

I have created a simple chat system. I have been trying but I cannot figure out how to limit the AJAX request on the page. In the console I am getting the error `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` and occasionally `net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`. I know you can use `limit` but I can't seem to use it right. Can someone please help me?

```
var form = document.querySelector('form[name="chatbox"]');
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

function submitChat() {
  if (chatbox.message.value == '') {
    alert('Error: Missing Fields.');
    return;
  }
  var message = chatbox.message.value;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 100) {
      document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open('GET', 'chat.php?message=' + message, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  chatbox.reset();
}
//AJAX STARTS HERE
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  debugger;
  setInterval(function() {$.ajax('logs.php', {
    ifModified: true,
    complete: function (jqxhrResponse) {
      $('#chatlog').html(jqxhrResponse.responseText);

      //SCROLL MESSAGE STARTS HERE
      function scrollToNewMessage() {
          if (allowScroll) {
        $("#chatlog").animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatlog').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  })});
});

var allowScroll = true;
$('#chatlog').scroll(function () {
  allowScroll = isNearBottom();
});

function isNearBottom() {
  var leeway = 10;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    return $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - leeway;
  });
}
```

Bonus: Can someone help me with the function `scrollToNewMessage()`? It is not working (doesn't scroll down to the new message).

Thank you!

Comment: for starters: the url you construct for your XHR request isn't good: 'chat.php?message=' + message. WHat if message contains spaces, etc? url encode the message. ALso, be sure to check your errorlog for javascript. Does it contain errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console besides `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`

Comment: Maybe the response of the server is huge? Test this by entering the url directly into a browser.

Comment: I don't think so. Putting `chat.php?message=test` into the URL gets a response quick. Although I am seeing a new error in the console saying `net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`